# How can I stop history go back if we are loading React app on a new page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, history.js

How can I easily implement a back and forward button in a react app? I have a set of pages that the user can browse through. I just want to implement a couple of buttons at the bottom that helps the user browse back and forth without using the browser buttons.

I am using a History component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


class History extends Component {

  handleBack = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack()
  }

  handleForward = () => {
    this.props.history.go(1)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigation-container">
        <div className="navigation-row">
          <span onClick={this.handleBack} className="back">
            BACK
          </span>
          <span onClick={this.handleForward} className="next ">
            NEXT
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(History)
```

In my App.js I have:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/menu/:section" exact component={Section}/>
    <Route component={Error} />
</Switch>
<History />
```

When a load a new page, load my application localhost and then click "Back", it goes to the blank "new page" in the browser. Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for your issue, there is a lot of solution and each solution is related to its own problems. for example, you can use the `Link` component of `react-router-dom` and then directly pass the route:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

~~~

<Link to="/prev-route">
  Prev
</Link>

<Link to="/next-route">
  Next
</Link>
```

Or you can use the `push` function of `history` that passed by using `withRouter` like below:

```
handleBack = () => {
  this.props.history.push('/prev-route');
};

handleForward = () => {
  this.props.history.push('/next-route');
};
```

Or for some rare cases, there is native browser API to do something like this:

```
handleBack = () => {
  this.props.history.back();
};

handleForward = () => {
  this.props.history.forward();
};
```

Definitely, on a ReactJS project, I use `react-router-dom` solutions.